# Is there a name for reading things how you meant to write them?

Tags: bias, reading

I'm sure many of us have this experience: 
When I'm proofreading my own writing I will pass over it multiple times, but miss mistakes since I read what I intended to write (what's "in my head") and not what is actually on the page.

Is there a name for this? I tried searching google, but had no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unofficially, it has been called "illusion of expectation" by Christopher Chabris and Daniel Simons, the guys famous for the [Invisible Gorilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness#Invisible_Gorilla_Test) experiment.

Technically it falls under [inattentional blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness#Blindness_despite_fixation) (or perceptual blindness):

> ... the event in which an individual fails to recognize an unexpected
>   stimulus that is in plain sight.

Comment: N.B,: the terminology in the paper found by AliceD is "word skipping".

Comment: @Fizz You mean in [his answer to this related question in relation to skipping 'this'](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/13971/21)?