# Why does the brain skip over repeated "the" words in sentences?

Tags: perception, language, reading, language-processing

For example, in this sentence by the the time you are done reading you will have already skipped over the double "the".

I have searched this on the internet a little, but I have found nothing that focuses on why this happens and shows actual proof and not just a hunch someone has on why it happens.  Would someone explain this and post a link to a trustworthy website that explains it in more detail.

[image: double the illusion]

Comment: Related: [Omitting word(s) when typing](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/18442/7001), [Is there a name for reading things how you meant to write them?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8636/7001)

Answer (score 14):

A study by [Rainer *et al*. (2011)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3543826/) has shown that words are skipped and apparently filled in mentally quite often (in the order of 8 to 30% of times).

Two important factors that increased skipping rates were the *length* of the word and the *predictability* of the word due to contextual constraints. Both cases apply on the word '*the*', because it is **short** and **highly predictable**, being a common [adjective](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/the) and in fact one of the [most used words](http://www.trussel.com/the.htm) in the English language. In other words, besides being short and predictable, it is also a very common word that has relatively little impact on the meaning of a sentence.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Rainer *et al*., *J Exp Psychol Hum Percept Perform* (2011); **37**(2): 514–28](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3543826/)</sub>